# What ToPrimitive is in + operator

Tags: javascript, coercion

```js
var a = [1,2];
var b = [3,4];

console.log(a + b); // "1,23,4"
```

Came across the paragraph at [this](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/types%20%26%20grammar/ch4.md) trying to explain what happened

> According to ES5 spec section 11.6.1, the + algorithm (when an object value is an operand) will concatenate if either operand is either already a string, or if the following steps produce a string representation. So, when + receives an object (including array) for either operand, it first calls the ToPrimitive abstract operation (section 9.1) on the value, which then calls the [[DefaultValue]] algorithm (section 8.12.8) with a context hint of number.

I can't understand particularly `ToPrimitive` in the above context. Applying the above rules to the case above, JS Engine will try to check if `a` or `b` is `typeof String`, and since none of them are, a `ToPrimitive` operation will be applied on `a`.

Trying to understand what `ToPrimitive()` is,correct me if I'm wrong, [explanation](http://2ality.com/2012/01/object-plus-object.html) is that `ToPrimitive` can also be understand as `toString()`, `toNumber()` and etc? If that's the case, why the quoted context not saying `toString` directly instead of `ToPrimitive()`?

Comment: `ToPrimitive` is defined here: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-toprimitive

Comment: The paragraph you're quoting is definitely a bit confusing; I would recommend you instead just look [at the ES5 spec yourself](https://es5.github.io/#x11.6.1)